# Is there any concept of "time difference" between oscillations(with same angular frequency) ? If yes, then how do I visualise it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, oscillators

I encountered this question -

"Two particles are oscillating along two parallel lines, with the same frequency and amplitude. They pass each other, moving in opposite directions when their displacement is half of the amplitude. The mean positions of the two particles lie on a straight line perpendicular to the paths of the two particles. What is their phase difference."

The solution that I found in a book used the concept of time difference, and I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call the "time difference" can be represented as a **phase** difference.

A harmonic motion along a straight line can be written as

$x(t) = A \cos ( \Omega t + \Phi )$

being $A$ the amplitude, $\Omega = 2 \pi f$ the angular velocity, $f$ the frequency, $\Phi$ the phase.

You can look at this formula as the projection on the $x$-axis of a circular motion with constant angular velocity on a circle of radius $A$.

If you consider two harmonic motions with the same amplitude and frequency, you can interpret them as the projection on the $x$-axis of two particles moving on the same angular velocity on the same circle.

$x_1(t) = A \cos(\Omega t - \Phi_1)$
$x_2(t) = A \cos(\Omega t - \Phi_2)$

The difference $\Delta \Phi = \Phi_2 - \Phi_1$ of phase is the (constant) angle between the two particles moving on the circle. This can be written as $\Delta \Phi = \Phi_2 - \Phi_1 = \Omega ( t_2 - t_1 ) = \Omega \Delta t$, making it appear the difference of time $\Delta t$, representing the time interval that needs to the oscillation 2 to reach the point identifying the current position of the oscillation 1, i.e.

$x_1(t) = A \cos(\Omega t - \Phi_1) =  A \cos(\Omega (t - t_1))$
$x_2(t) = A \cos(\Omega t - \Phi_2) =  A \cos(\Omega (t - t_2)) = A \cos(\Omega (t - t_1 - \Delta t))$ ,

so that $x_1(t) = x_2(t + \Delta t)$.

Comment: You explained phase difference, and I get it. However, can you explain time difference as a concept in itself?

Comment: I edited my previous answer. Let me now if it's clear now and we can be satisfied with it

Comment: It is clear now. Thanks!